# c++: AWS S3 Object Lambda

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

AWS recently introduced S3 Object Lambda, however looking at the online documentation:

- [Writing and debugging Lambda functions for S3 Object Lambda Access Points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/olap-writing-lambda.html)
- [Introducing Amazon S3 Object Lambda – Use Your Code to Process Data as It Is Being Retrieved from S3](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/)
- [How to use Amazon S3 Object Lambda to generate thumbnails](https://olena-k.medium.com/how-to-use-amazon-s3-object-lambda-to-generate-thumbnails-e16ae36a33ea)

I can only find example for Java, Python and NodeJS.

Is there an example out there for c++ that I missed ? In particular I fail to understand what is the equivalent in c++ for `getObjectContext` (python/nodejs) / `S3ObjectLambdaEvent` (java) ? How should I retrieve `outputRoute`, `outputToken`, `inputS3Url` ? The integration test does not make it particularly clear either:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/main/aws-cpp-sdk-s3-integration-tests/BucketAndObjectOperationTest.cpp#L580-L581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own post after a couple of weeks of struggle.

Basic point is summarized at [Introduction to Amazon S3 Object Lambda](https://antonputra.com/introduction-to-amazon-s3-object-lambda/)

The JSON payload of interest is simply:

```
{   "xAmzRequestId": "1a5ed718-5f53-471d-b6fe-5cf62d88d02a",   
    "getObjectContext": {
      "inputS3Url": "https://transform-424432388155.s3-accesspoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/title.txt?X-Amz-Security-Token=...",
      "outputRoute": "io-iad-cell001",
      "outputToken": "..."   },
```

You can simply open it using:

```
static invocation_response my_handler(invocation_request const& req, Aws::S3::S3Client const& client)
{
    using namespace Aws::Utils::Json;
    JsonValue json(req.payload);
    if (!json.WasParseSuccessful()) {
        return invocation_response::failure("Failed to parse input JSON", "InvalidJSON");
    }

    auto view = json.View();
    auto s3url = view.GetObject("getObjectContext").GetString("inputS3Url");
    auto route = view.GetObject("getObjectContext").GetString("outputRoute");
    auto token = view.GetObject("getObjectContext").GetString("outputToken");
```

Which will later be used in WriteGetObjectResponseRequest as:

```
S3::Model::WriteGetObjectResponseRequest request;
request.WithRequestRoute(route);
request.WithRequestToken(token);
request.SetBody(objectStream);
auto outcome = client.WriteGetObjectResponse(request);
```

It is then up to the application to decide on how to construct the objectStream, but a simple pass-through example would be:

```
std::shared_ptr<Aws::Http::HttpRequest> getRequest =
  CreateHttpRequest(s3url, Http::HttpMethod::HTTP_GET,                        
  Aws::Utils::Stream::DefaultResponseStreamFactoryMethod);
std::shared_ptr<Aws::Http::HttpClient> httpClient = 
  Aws::Http::CreateHttpClient(Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration());
std::shared_ptr<Aws::Http::HttpResponse> getResponse =
  httpClient->MakeRequest(getRequest);
std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> objectStream = 
  Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("SO-WriteGetObjectResponse");
const Aws::IOStream& responseBody = getResponse->GetResponseBody();
*objectStream << responseBody.rdbuf();
objectStream->flush();
```

Examples which help me are:

- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp/blob/master/examples/s3/main.cpp
- [Working with WriteGetObjectResponse (Example #2/Python)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/olap-writing-lambda.html#olap-getobject-response)

Answer (score 0):

S3 Object Lambda is using the AWS Lambda service. AWS Lambda does only support the following runtimes "natively":

- Go
- .NET Core
- Ruby
- Java
- Python
- NodeJS

C++ is support through "custom" runtimes or through Docker containers. Usually, the AWS documentation only covers the "natively" supported runtimes and even then not all (as you noticed). Mostly they have examples for the most popular ones.

So what you need to look for are C++ Lambda examples, examples using the C++ AWS SDK and reference documentation.

Using the reference documentation and the Java/Python/NodeJS examples, it should be easy to write a C++ version.

For example:

1. [Introducing the C++ Lambda Runtime (Blog Post)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/)
2. [C++ AWS SDK Page](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/)
3. [API Reference for WriteGetObjectResponseRequest](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_s3_1_1_model_1_1_write_get_object_response_request.html)

Comment: Could you trim everything before and after `it should be easy to write a C++ version`, that will make the answer clearer, thanks.

Comment: @malat Not sure what you mean. Can you please explain.

Comment: it's just sarcasm